# Inserting an array into every nth element of another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 arrays:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
['g', 'h', 'i']
```

I need to insert elements of second array after every second element (or nth) of the first array, resulting in:

```
['a', 'b', 'g', 'c', 'd', 'h', 'e', 'f', 'i']
```

Is there an easy way for me to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always use a custom [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Enumerator.html):

```
a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
a2 = ['g', 'h', 'i']

enum = Enumerator.new do |y|
  e1 = a1.each
  e2 = a2.each
  loop do
    y << e1.next << e1.next << e2.next
  end
end

enum.to_a #=> ["a", "b", "g", "c", "d", "h", "e", "f", "i"]
```

Or for the general case:

```
n.times { y << e1.next }
```

Comment: Wonderful. I also tried to return an Enumerator, but my code was an ugly mess because I didn't think about using a1.each.

Comment: Creative. I guess you could use any method on the arrays which returns an enumerator, `to_enum` included.

Comment: This is a nice one!

Answer (score 7):

Something like this:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
b = ['g', 'h', 'i']
a.each_slice(2). # => [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]
  zip(b). # => [[["a", "b"], "g"], [["c", "d"], "h"], [["e", "f"], "i"]]
  flatten # => ['a', 'b', 'g', 'c', 'd', 'h', 'e', 'f', 'i']
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Wasted far too much time doing stupid stuff with this!

Comment: It will generate `nil` items when `a.each_slice(1).zip(b).flatten` => `["a", "g", "b", "h", "c", "i", "d", nil, "e", nil, "f", nil]` . So need add `compact` ... `a.each_slice(1).zip(b).flatten.compact`

Comment: @AlexKojin This might be the desired behaviour. Who knows? (Mark, that's who)

Comment: It just means that `a.each_slice(2)` should be written as `a.each_slice(n)` with `n=2` as method parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
b=['g', 'h', 'i']
b.each.with_index(1) { |e,i| a.insert((3*i)-1,e) }

a
#=> ['a', 'b', 'g', 'c', 'd', 'h', 'e', 'f', 'i']
```

Comment: This will modify `a`, though.

Comment: Ah yes, it appears to be desired behaviour.