# Insert after every nth comma in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following string and array:

```
a = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8'
b = ['9', '10', '11', '12']
```

I need to insert an element of b after every nth comma (2 for this example) into a, resulting in:

```
a = '1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 10, 5, 6, 11, 7, 8, 12'
```

I've been playing around with various forms of [scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-scan) but can't seem to produce the desired result.

Is there an easy way for me to do this?

Comment: Please look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991417/inserting-an-array-into-every-nth-element-of-another/40991568), and try to approach like that for your problem.

Comment: @31piy : Notice something? it's the same OP :D

Comment: Indeed - apologies but seemed like a different question - I'll turn the first into an array and delete this question?

Comment: @EricDuminil I didn't pay attention that this question was asked by the same person. :D

Comment: Whoa Déjà vu...

Comment: Why did you just ask the same question again?

Comment: As I said was under the impression it was a different question, have flagged a moderator to remove as I can't delete.

Answer (score 0):

Use `a.split(', ')`, any solution from your previous question, and `join(', ')`.

With credits to @Stefan :

```
a = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8'
b = ['9', '10', '11', '12']

enum = Enumerator.new do |y|
  e1 = a.split(',').each
  e2 = b.each
  loop do
    y << e1.next.strip << e1.next.strip << e2.next
  end
end

puts enum.to_a.join(', ')

#=> 1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 10, 5, 6, 11, 7, 8, 12
```

You could also use this if you are sure that every number is separated by a comma **and** a space :

```
enum = Enumerator.new do |y|
  e1 = a.split(', ').each
  e2 = b.each
  loop do
    y << e1.next << e1.next << e2.next
  end
end
```

Comment: Isn't this copied from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991417/inserting-an-array-into-every-nth-element-of-another#answer-40992356

Comment: Yes it is. Same OP, almost the same question, almost the same answer. I mention @Stefan in my answer.